# VB 2010 Store Passwords In Database

Tags: vb.net, passwords

Im using vb.net (visual studio 2010) and have made a form application that uses a login screen.
All that works but im having trouble any firm way to encrypt the passwords in the database. 
The encryption doesnt have to be very high standard as its just for a college project.

Whats the best way to encrypt the password into the database?
Or just encrypt the password string, i can then sort out the database end myself.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are more that one way to encrypt password with the .NET framework. It depend on how secure it should be based on your requirements.

A very common way is to use the MD5 encryption, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx)

Comment: MD5 would be hashing; not encryption. It is however a viable means of protection for the project in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can select from one of the many classes in `System.Security.Cryptography` to handle the encryption/decryption such as [Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) (sample code of encrypting/decrypting a string in the link).